# why interface in typescript sometimes need to strict to match attributes, sometimes not

Tags: typescript

```
interface LabeledValue {
  label: string;
}

function printLabel(labeledObj: LabeledValue) {
  console.log(labeledObj.label);
}

let myObj = { size: 10, label: "Size 10 Object" }; // not err  

let myObj1: LabeledValue = { size: 10, label: "Size 10 Object" }; // err 

printLabel(myObj);
```

myObj and myObj1 both need to achieve LabeledValue interface. why myObj1 has an err?

Comment: the interface directly acts on an object must match exactly？？？

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, the error does not occur because the expected type is not specified, in the second case the keys do not match in the object and type, so an error occurs

```
interface LabeledValue {
  label: string;
  size: number;  // <----------- insert 
  // or size?: number; if you want sometimes skip it
}

function printLabel(labeledObj: LabeledValue) {
  console.log(labeledObj.label);
}

let myObj = { size: 10, label: "Size 10 Object" }; // not err  

let myObj1: LabeledValue = { size: 10, label: "Size 10 Object" }; // not err 

printLabel(myObj);
```

read more https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#optional-and-default-parameters

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that if you create variable and specify the type, TS expects you to be specific.

However, for things like function arguments the Liskov principle applies. You just need to pass something that's compatible.

I'm having a hard time answering specifically why, because this is a design choice. However, I think it's a really good design choice.

If I need to pass X to a function I want it to be able to accept something that 'extends X', because I don't want the extra step to convert the object.

However, when it's inline I know *exactly* what object I'm creating, so it would be weird to give the object a simpler type.

So I think it's simply a good default. Had the function or the inline type worked different, it would have been a major source of frustration.

Answer (score 0):

In general, Typescript has structural type system and extra properties do not prevent assignment. The exemption are object literals, which are treated "more strictly".
This is called [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks):

> Object literals get special treatment and undergo excess property checking when **assigning them to other variables, or passing them as arguments**. If an object literal has any properties that the “target type” doesn’t have, you’ll get an error